# Is there a password manager server application

Tags: password, webserver

Yet another hackers attack on the infrastructure of companies that offer to store our passwords begs the question:

> Is there a password manager server application? (Along with browser extensions)

That is an application that stores passwords in a **personal** server (that is publicly accessible), but which is can be connected in a variety of browsers and across many computers.

In essence, a sort of `lastpass` service but with the lastpass server running on a personal server, not on the cloud.

The key here is, of course, the decentralization of password storage, which would make it less interesting for hackers to try and breach the security and get access to someone's personal data.

I am using [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/119892/company-password-management) post as a guide, but it is not clear if even the enterprise solutions are run on personal servers.

Preferably the application should

- be free software and / or open source
- run on a Linux / Unix server
- have extensions for browsers (especially Firefox) across many archs

Comment: [pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/) + [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/): FOSS, secure, completely controlled by you...

Comment: Have a look at teampass: http://www.teampass.net/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/communitypasswo/

Comment: This page shows how to set up `webkeepass`, perhaps this is something that suits you: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-web-based-enterprise-password-manager-protected-by-two-factor-authentication

Comment: @jasonwryan Hi there. I was looking into both applications. So in essence what you propose is to have a password-store file that I sync across my computers? I will always have to access the command line to grab a password for a website. But what do I do on windows pc's ?

Comment: I have no idea: I don't use Windows and as your criteria specified FOSS, I did not think to investigate it further...